# NSPredicate - fetch entities with to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Considering `Action` with an `assignedTo` relationship to `User` entity. (Action.assignedTo->>User)

What would be a query that selects all `actions` which contain the `user` in the `assignedTo` set?

Comment: `@"self.assignedTo == %@" theWantedUser"`?

Comment: `assignedTo` is a set (to-many relation from Action to User)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subquery is a bit heavy handed. 
You can use this :

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY assignedTo.userId == %@", user.userId];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your model files using the `Xcode` generator for `CoreData`?

If so, check your User.h file, you should see something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet         *actions;
```

That mean that you can call all the actions of that user just calling:

```
NSSet *userActions = user.actions;
```

No need to use a predicate.

If still you want to use a predicate, the predicate should look like this:

```
NSPredicate *userPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"assignedTo == %@",user];
```

If you need to add aditional predicates you should you an array of them a make a NSCompoundPredicate:

```
NSPredicate *anotherPredicate= ...;
//andPredicateWithSubpredicates if you want the both 
//orPredicateWithSubpredicates if you want at least one of them
NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = (NSPredicate*)[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[userPredicate,anotherPrediate]]
```

Comment: I agree that using the inverse relationship would work, but if I need to filter the actions also by `status` then I still need to use `NSPredicate`.

Comment: I know that internally core data keeps a link table for many-to-many relationship associations, so I imagine there must be a way to fetch those entities efficiently.

Comment: you should use a NSCompoundPrediate, i had edited my answer, is that what you need?

Comment: I've found a better solution myself. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I found that **`SUBQUERY`** is the right answer here; it works perfect:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"(SUBQUERY(assignedTo, $a, $a.userId == %ld).@count != 0)", user.userId];
```

and with filter by `status`

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"(SUBQUERY(assignedTo, $a, $a.userId == %ld).@count != 0) && status != 'Completed'", user.userId];
```